# Errors in Ice4j Source: Duplicate Methods

Tags: java, jar, ice4j

I am trying to export Ice4j to a jar file to use in my project, but there is an error and I don't know how to fix it because I have never seen this before and Google has little information about it. I copied the files straight from the svn with no edits, so I'll post the source below.

```
Duplicate methods named spliterator with the parameters () and () are inherited from the types Collection<CandidateHarvester> and Iterable<CandidateHarvester>
Duplicate methods named spliterator with the parameters () and () are inherited from the types Set<CandidateHarvester> and Collection<CandidateHarvester>
```

The bit of code is below:

```
public class CandidateHarvesterSet
    extends AbstractSet<CandidateHarvester>
{
```

The full file is here: https://code.google.com/p/ice4j/source/browse/trunk/src/org/ice4j/ice/harvest/CandidateHarvesterSet.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, changing the JRE system library from JRE8 to JRE7 works.